# How can I train SVM in Matlab, with more than 2 classes

Tags: matlab, svm

I was trying to use [fitcsvm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) to train and classify my data. However, I notice - correct me if I'm wrong - that fitcsvm could only be used with 2 classes (groups).

My data have more than 2 classes. Is there away to do classify them in matlab?

I did some googling and I read that some recommend to use [fitcecoc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcecoc.html), while others recommend to use out of the box code [multisvm](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39352-multi-class-svm)

Morover, other recommend to use [discriminant analysis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/discriminant-analysis.html)

Please, advise on best approach to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct, **fitcsvm** is for one or two classes, you may use **svmtrain** which is *matlab's* svm classifier for more then two classes, also there is a famous toolbox named **libsvm**, if you google it would be found easily.

https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm

Recently I saw some new method for multiply svm classifer named **DSVM**, it's nice new method,this would be found in matlab's files exchange.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48632-multiclass-svm-classifier

good luck

Comment: if this is help, let me know :)